# how to read .txt file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i used this code this working fine but i want to use arduino web server. when i connect arduino web server than show  direct file in table.not using upload.

//code is here

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function Upload() {

        var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
        
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var table = document.createElement("table");
 
                    table.style.width = '75%';
                  
                    table.setAttribute('border', '2'); // for table border
                  
                    var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        
                        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                        var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                        for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                            var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                            cell.innerHTML = cells[j];
                        }
                    }
                    var dvCSV = document.getElementById("dvCSV");
                    dvCSV.innerHTML = "";
                    dvCSV.appendChild(table);
                }
                reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0]);
              
           
       
    }
</script>
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" /> 
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" onclick="Upload()" /> 
<hr />
<div id="dvCSV">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you store the file on your webserver or somewhere else on the internet you can just fetch it and read it.

```
document.onLoad=function(){
  fetch("https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt").then(response=>Upload(response.text()))
}
```

Comment: Why downvote without adding a comment? This actually solves the problem and is the easiest way to "read" a text file without having the user upload it.

Comment: I used Arduino ethernet shields with web server. is this work with arduino webserver? and Not Any server Instal in. is this work? now m using iframe to view my file.